# Converted video from .VOB have no voice

Tags: sound, video, dvd, video-conversion, format-conversion

I'm stock on this for a while.

I have tried

```
ffmpeg -i inpout.VOB -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 192k output.avi
```

and

```
mencoder in.VOB -nosub -nosound -ovc x264 \
-x264encopts direct=auto:pass=2:bitrate=900:frameref=5:bframes=1:\
me=umh:partitions=all:trellis=1:qp_step=4:qcomp=0.7:direct_pred=auto:keyint=300 \
-vf scale=-1:-10,harddup -o out.avi
```

and also

```
ffmpeg -i input.VOB output.mk4
```

But in all cased the resulting videos are voiceless, while the original inpout.VOB has voice when played with VLC.

So I'm wondering what's the correct command to do the conversion?

Comment: Could you pastebin the FFmpeg command and complete terminal output? Better to use the mp4 container btw. Also which version of Ubuntu you are using...

Comment: sorry the output terminal is gone. It will takes ages to repeat each command.

Comment: Terminal out put will show details about your version of FFmpeg, the composition of the input file as well as errors in transcoding to the output file. Use `-frames 200` to encode a shorter and quicker sample...

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by converting the audio and the video separately, then merging them with MKVToolNix. BTW you can convert only a small portion of the video (for testing) using the `-ss 120 -t 30` parameters.